# How can I tell Symfony2 to always use _format=json for a certain URL pattern?

Tags: symfony

I'd like the response for any URL starting with `/api` to be in JSON format. Is there a way to configure this for my whole application? I'm using Symfony2 version 2.0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using annotations for routes and activate controllers in `routing.yml`, you could do this:

```
Api:
    resource: "@ApiBundle/Controller"
    type: annotation
    defaults: { _format: 'json' }
```

If you want to set it for one controller only, set it on the controller level annotation:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/api", defaults={"_format": "json"})
 */
class ApiController 
{
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I have one bundle with many controllers, one of which is `APIController`. Route annotations are configured as you've specified, but most controllers in the bundle serve HTML. `APIController` serves everything from `/api`, so can I just set the default `_format` for that class? If this isn't possible, I can just pull `APIController` out into a separate bundle and do what you suggest.